# Spark 2.0.x dump a csv file from a dataframe containing one array of type string

Tags: arrays, csv, apache-spark

I have a dataframe `df` that contains one column of type array

`df.show()` looks like

```
|ID|ArrayOfString|Age|Gender|
+--+-------------+---+------+
|1 | [A,B,D]     |22 | F    |
|2 | [A,Y]       |42 | M    |
|3 | [X]         |60 | F    |
+--+-------------+---+------+
```

I try to dump that `df` in a csv file as follow:

```
val dumpCSV = df.write.csv(path="/home/me/saveDF")
```

It is not working because of the column `ArrayOfString`.  I get the error:

> CSV data source does not support array string data type

The code works if I remove the column `ArrayOfString`. But I need to keep `ArrayOfString`!

What would be the best way to dump the csv dataframe including column ArrayOfString (ArrayOfString  should be dumped as one column on the CSV file)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is that csv file format doesn't support array types, you'll need to express it as a string to be able to save.

Try the following :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val stringify = udf((vs: Seq[String]) => vs match {
  case null => null
  case _    => s"""[${vs.mkString(",")}]"""
})

df.withColumn("ArrayOfString", stringify($"ArrayOfString")).write.csv(...)
```

or

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def stringify(c: Column) = concat(lit("["), concat_ws(",", c), lit("]"))

df.withColumn("ArrayOfString", stringify($"ArrayOfString")).write.csv(...)
```

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for the answer. I understand what those lines does. However I am a bit confused of the syntax s"""[${vs.mkString(",")}]"""   Could you explain me a bit more about the s and the triple """   ? Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html `"""` because there is embedded `"`

Comment: Hum I understand better the meaning of "s" thanks to the doc you send me. However I still not understand why 3 quotes. Why can't I write  s"[${vs.mkString(",")}]"   By the way using 1 quote also works on my side. So why 3 quotes?

Answer (score 36):

No need for a UDF if you already know which fields contain arrays. You can simply use Spark's cast function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dumpCSV = df.withColumn("ArrayOfString", col("ArrayOfString").cast("string"))
                .write
                .csv(path="/home/me/saveDF")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This should be the top answer, it’s using an inbuilt function to solve the question.

Answer (score 29):

Pyspark implementation.

In this example, change the field `column_as_array` to `column_as_string` before saving.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def array_to_string(my_list):
    return '[' + ','.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list]) + ']'

array_to_string_udf = udf(array_to_string, StringType())

df = df.withColumn('column_as_str', array_to_string_udf(df["column_as_array"]))
```

Then you can drop the old column (array type) before saving.

```py
df.drop("column_as_array").write.csv(...)
```

Comment: I have 2 columns "Antecedent" and "Consequent" which has list as input. How can I modify this code to do the same.

Comment: It worked for me (and one could even automatize it by creating a list `all_mappings = [x for (x,y) in df_p300.dtypes if y == 'map<string,int>' ]` ). Small detail: the last line of the first block of code should read `df["column_as_array"]` instead of `d["column_as_array"]`.

Comment: Can someone fix the `d` to `df` as @LionelTrebuchon mentioned? SO does not allow one character edit, but this example works, but this one typo.

Comment: character typo fixed, thanks to LionelTrebuchon and @zeh

Answer (score 11):

Here is a method for converting all `ArrayType` (of any underlying type) columns of a `DataFrame` to `StringType` columns:

```scala
def stringifyArrays(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val colsToStringify = dataFrame.schema.filter(p => p.dataType.typeName == "array").map(p => p.name)
  colsToStringify.foldLeft(dataFrame)((df, c) => {
    df.withColumn(c, concat(lit("["), concat_ws(", ", col(c).cast("array<string>")), lit("]")))
  })
}
```

Also, it doesn't use a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is not the ideal export format, but if you just want to visually inspect your data, this will work [Scala]. Quick and dirty solution.

```
case class example ( id: String, ArrayOfString: String, Age: String, Gender: String)

df.rdd.map{line => example(line(0).toString, line(1).toString, line(2).toString , line(3).toString) }.toDF.write.csv("/tmp/example.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer DreamerP's question (from one of the comments) :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def array_to_string(my_list):
    return '[' + ','.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list]) + ']'

array_to_string_udf = udf(array_to_string, StringType())

df = df.withColumn('Antecedent_as_str', array_to_string_udf(df["Antecedent"]))
df = df.withColumn('Consequent_as_str', array_to_string_udf(df["Consequent"]))
df = df.drop("Consequent")
df = df.drop("Antecedent")
df.write.csv("foldername")
```